# Unexpected use of 'name' no-restricted-globals in template string ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to ReactJS (and javascript) and got an online course to watch. I am following the classes and just copied the code from the video, but am getting the error mentioned above (Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals). I've seen similar questions, but none seemed to work on my case, and I have no idea on how to fix this.

The error happens on the handlePClick method on the code below (which is just the default code for a react app)

````
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component<{}, { name: string }> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePClick = this.handlePClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name: "Julia",
    };
  }

  handlePClick() {
    console.log(`<p> clicado ${name}`);
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p onClick={this.handlePClick}>{name}</p>
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.state.name` instead of `name`

```
console.log(`<p> clicado ${this.state.name}`);
```